# How would you evaluate this series in regards to Fourier series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, laplace-transform, fourier-transform

The question:

> Evaluate the series
>   $$
> 1 + \frac 19 + \frac 1{25} + \frac 1{49} + \cdots
> $$

All the information given is that it is in relation to a Fourier series and that the series is to be evaluated.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8378/81360) computes a similar sum using Fourier series, perhaps you can get an idea from there

Comment: Where would I begin?

Comment: I don't really know how you should begin.  Another idea I have is that the instructor might have a trick in mind where you plug in to some Fourier series formula that you have.  Do you have some table of Fourier series?  Did you compute the Fourier series of a triangle wave in an earlier problem, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, one of my previous asked questions on this site

Comment: Perfect.  Once you have the answer to [the question you're referring to,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2835791/81360)  it will be sufficient to plug in $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is as follows:

Let $f(t)$ denote a triangle wave with the precise form [described here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesTriangleWave.html) (we'll take $L = 1$).  As you can see in the link, $f$ can be expanded into its Fourier series as
$$
f(t) = \frac{8}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^2} \sin ((2n - 1) \pi t)
$$
Now, just plug $t = \frac 12$ into both sides of the equation above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** On way to evaluate your series is using [Parseval theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem). At first you need to find the fourier series of a function like $f(x)=x$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$ and then applying Parseval theorem.

In our example, the function is odd and you should find the series of it.

Comment: Also here is a ref: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437102/how-to-find-11-221-32-using-fourier-series?rq=1

Comment: and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2793747/108128